# TinyMCE: are <input> elements wrongly handled?

Tags: forms, input, tinymce

I am encoutering various weird issues with `<input>` tags in TinyMCE (version 6, and also 5.8.2).

After entering the following in "code" view:

`<input name="submit" value="myval" type="text">`

I click "Save", the input field appears in the WYSIWYG view, but if I open the code view again, the `name="submit"` part has been removed. This does not happen with values other than "submit". Do you know why?

Also, the element selection does not work on inputs: with the following code:

```
<form>
<p>Firstname</p>
<input name="firstname" value="John" type="text">
</form>
```

Clicking on "Firstname" shows `form > p` in the editor footer, but clicking on the input field only shows `p`, like if the `input` element was not properly recognized.
Any clue to fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why would you name a text input field "submit"? I imagine it isn't allowed due to a potential naming conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I kind of agree, however, it at least works from a HTML viewpoint, and it was working with older versions of TinyMCE. I have to live with legacy production code, so I would like to at least understand what has changed in TinyMCE (could not find out by reading the source code), in order to make a reliable change if required.